# External gate resistor calculation

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am trying to find external gate resistance value for my MOSFET.

Here are some details:

I am using IRFP4468PbF power hexfet mosfet - [Datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfp4468pbf.pdf)

80V, 500mA, 3-Phase MOSFET Driver - [Datasheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/hip4/hip4086-a.pdf)

I had worked out through some formula and found that
 I=0.77A (using I= Qg/ Dt),

T= 702ns ( using ton + toff = T)
so f = 1.4 Mhz

Qg = 540nC
so Cg = 45nC (using Cg = Qg/V) V= 12V

P(power dissipation)= 9.072 watts ( using Cg x Vdd^2 x f)

Now when I find the resistance, I got value 15ohms ( which I dont feel its correct) After reading couple of things online. I thought that it should be around 0.15 - 0.45. 
So I want to know where I am going wrong and what is right.

Comment: Doesn't sound way out to me. Except for power dissipation. What frequency are you actually going to be switching at?

Comment: I am thinking of 30khz

Comment: so you will only be sourcing or sinking 540nC every 15uS not every 0.7us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you don't want much of a gate resistor when you're using a driver IC. Think about it. The resistor limits the current into the gate. The purpose of the gate driver is to push a bunch of current into the gate to turn it on faster. The two work against each other. I would start off with a set of pads populated with a \$ 0 \Omega\$ resistor. If you run into ringing during testing, you can swap out the \$ 0 \Omega\$ for \$ 10-100 \Omega\$ to increase the damping coefficient. It's hard to model and calculate this stuff with all the parasitics involved. There is no substitute for good testing in the application.